# Aiflow exceeds pool slot limit

Tags: airflow

After a period of time airflow exceeds the slot limit defined for a particular pool. It works fine after a reboot, looking for a permanent solution for this.

Airflow version - 1.6.2

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pool oversubscription is supposed to be a known issue up until 1.7.1.3. I think this is going to be fixed in the next release (not entirely sure though).